# What happen to definitions in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been working a project involving C++ and Python code using VScode.

Until now there was a very useful feature in which I can right click a variable and select Go to Definition or "Peek" and it will show me the definition of said variable.

Suddenly today I tried to do the same but now there is a "No definition found" message.

I wonder what happened to this VS Code feature?

Comment: Is your code working fine??

Comment: Yes. One poppup appeared all of a sudden and after pressing it, now intellisense works fine. Unfortunately I have no idea what this was...